# Docker Compose Spring Boot + Postgresql (No Route to Host)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I can not run my spring boot project with postgreslq using docker-compose. (I could run with jar command and from IDE)

Errors:

```java
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     ... 21 common frames omitted
temassiz-menu-spring-boot | Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:81) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:93) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
temassiz-menu-spring-boot |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
```

- Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/application.jar"]
```

- docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: temassiz-menu-spring-boot
    image: temassiz-menu-spring-boot-image
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - dbpostgresql
  dbpostgresql:
    container_name: temassiz-menu-postgresql
    image: library/postgres:12.4
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=testdatabase
```

- application.properties file inside spring boot project

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://dbpostgresql:5431/testdatabase
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
```

I assume that this error is related to some network config inside pg_hba.config, I added to some config to this file, but it did not work.

- pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# I tried 172... with md5 and peer methods
host    all             all             172.16.0.0/32           md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

- `docker ps` after running docker-compose

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2fc8d90e1e71        postgres:12.4       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:5431->5432/tcp   temassiz-menu-postgresql
```

- docker inspect for postgres:

```json
...
"MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "temassiz-menu-rest_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "dbpostgresql",
                        "2fc8d90e1e71"
                    ],
                    
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.24.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

According to @David Maze and @richyen answers:

1. I changed the ports to :

```yaml
ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

- Then `docker-compose --build` gave this error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
```

- After that i just run the following command to stop postgres service:

```sh
$ service postgresql-12.service stop
```

- After all `docker-compose --build` gave me the same error `java.net.NoRouteToHostException:`

2. I removed ports section completely, and run `docker-compose --build`, it gave me the same response `java.net.NoRouteToHostException:`

Comment: You always need to use the standard port number for inter-container connections; `ports:` aren't considered (or required).  Change the port number in the URL to 5432.

Comment: I believe your port mapping `5431:5432` is incorrect.  For containers within the same network, they will talk to the internal ports (`5432`) in your case.  The port mapping for `5431` is for you to communicate with the container from within your host OS, outside the container's network

Comment: Thank you for quick responses, but changing or removing ports from the configuration did not work, i updated my question.

Comment: Do the next. First start your DB with ```docker-compose up -d dbpostgresql``` wait a bit for it to start (check logs is DB started). Then check, can you connect to database from hosting machine. If you can start your app by ```docker-compose up -d app```. I suspect DB is not ready when your app try to connect it.

Comment: Here is docker-compose from one of my projects. Hope it helps - https://gitlab.com/gintsgints/vue-fullstack/-/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @GintsGints, i run the `docker-compose up -d dbpostgresql` then run the following command, and I succeed the connect psql `psql -U postgres -p 32773 -h localhost` , but my spring boot application gave me the same error `NoRoute..`

Comment: on which OS are you working, and what is your docker version ? have you tried to run the docker-compose using root user ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi docker-version= `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d` and OS=Fedora, I tried as `sudo docker-compose up --build` but not it didn't work.

Comment: have a look at this [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-route-to-host-network-request-from-container-to-host-ip-port-published-from-other-container/39063/12) it could help you ;)

Comment: I have solved it, i just whitelisted the docker (take a look this site: https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/ )

Comment: Glad to see that you have solved the issue. Please add the answer for the same instead of updating the question and title.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit adding an answer in your question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay prior to accepting your own answer).